# More than one migrations configuration type was found in the assembly ''. Specify the name of the one to use. On add-migration

Tags: c#, migration, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

In Package Manager Console, I'm trying to update my database. When I enter this command :

```
add-migration Migration1
```

And I get this :

> More than one migrations configuration type was found in the assembly
>   'MyProject.POCO'. Specify the name of the one to use.

I googled the error and I get this :

```
add-migration InitialBSchema -IgnoreChanges -ConfigurationTypeName
ConfigurationB -ProjectName ProjectContextIsInIfNotMainOne
-StartupProjectName NameOfMainProject  -ConnectionStringName ContextB
```

But I don't know how to apply this to my project. What should I write for ConfigurationTypeName? Or is there a simpler way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have multiple `DbContext` in your project you will need to indicate which is going to have the database update. This can be done with `-ConfigurationTypeName`. The ConfigurationTypeName is the name of your Configuration class in your migration folder.

`Add-Migration -Name Migration1 -ConfigurationTypeName MyProject.POCO.Configuration`

You can read more about it [here.](http://www.mortenanderson.net/code-first-migrations-for-entity-framework)